# CSS to set top right corner color as shown in the link

Tags: css, border

https://www.figma.com/proto/XnCr58wlf3hKZ1bw6tgWbR/HM-Format?node-id=18%3A8&scaling=scale-down-width&page-id=0%3A1

Friends, can you help me to set the background color black on top corner (as shown in the link) along with the existing background color for the whole cell.

I am using HTML table for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one, you can get that triangular shape by using [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). The element which is clipped is a child element of the red box element

I used [this website](https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/) to create the desired clip-path.

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
}

.top-right {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: black;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 69% 0, 100% 31%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 69% 0, 100% 31%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-right"></div>
</div>
```